# How to install Safing (Portmaster) in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: software-installation, deb, 23.10, app-center

I fresh installed Ubuntu 23.10 after I couldn't upgrade from 23.10. Now I want to install Safing (Portmaster) in Ubuntu 23.10, but the App Center is not able to install Safing. How can I install Safing by using or not using the App Center?

I clicked the .deb file that I downloaded from the official [Safing website](https://safing.io/) to try to install the app, but the App Center was not able to install the Safing .deb file.

And is the app center will get fix so people can install apps like safing, using the app center?

Comment: See https://docs.safing.io/portmaster/install/linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you download the .deb package, open a terminal and type the below command:

```shell
sudo dpkg -i portmaster-installer.deb
```

Comment: i was able to install app safing using something similiar to the above only have to change the path. but i couldnt use. but using synaptic,it detected broken packages and after clicking in the menu to solve and apllied the app work. and thanks